# Get-Date -Format is giving different result to Get-Date

Tags: powershell

I am getting date and time in a variable which is different from my Server clock.

`QDate = $(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss tt")`

If I simply type `Get-Date` I can get the server local time but I am using this variable to insert time in SQL Database and I need the dates in given format.

```
> Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss tt" 
20190425 10:04:39

> Get-Date
April 25, 2019 10:07:28 AM
```

time difference 04 minutes

Comment: what kind of "different" are you talking about ? can you add an example ?

Comment: `$QDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss tt"` ?

Comment: Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss tt" 
20190425 10:04:39

Get-Date
April 25, 2019 10:07:28 AM

time difference 04 minutes

Comment: What is the type on the SQL Server end -- `DATETIME`, `DATETIMEOFFSET`, `VARCHAR`? Ideally, you should use parameterized SQL commands so you can pass the `Get-Date` value in a typed way, without futzing around with string representations at all, but if you must use strings, you should use one of the select few formats that SQL Server will interpret unambiguously regardless of regional settings (`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff` for `DATETIME`, `o` for `DATETIMEOFFSET`).

Comment: Your original difference is a simple consequence of `MM` standing for months and `mm` for minutes -- you're using `MM` twice. But, like I said, if the type on SQL Server is an actual date/time type, don't use that format at all -- it's not one of the unambiguous ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got...

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd hh:MM:ss tt"
```

You want...

```
Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss tt"
```

Note, the change in case of the "mm" for minutes,